# Building Oozie failes

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am using maven 3.2.1,java 1.7 and Oozie4.0.0. when I tried to build it I got maven plugin and dependency error.`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-client:jar:4.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at junit:junit:jar:4.10: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.10: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.10 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): repo1.maven.org: Name or service not known: Unknown host repo1.maven.org: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you can't access to repo1.maven.org. Try a another maven repo and check your internet connection ;)